# JsonObject gson not processing properly convert to string and int

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson, tostring

So I'm writing a `REST` app right now that receives some `JSON` from postman and parses it, calls my database, and then spits the object back up to postman (I'm aware this is basically just a `GET` right now. I've been doing this to get to the bottom of the issue).

I've tested this a few different times. If I return `res += company;` or `res += dept_id` back to postman, they both come back with their expected values.

However, if I do my `getDepartment(company, dept_id)`, the func fails and `oldDept` is not initialized. If I hardcode `getDepartment("CoolCarsInc",16)` then `oldDept` is initialized and shows up as expected in the output from postman.

So it seems extremely likely that there's something wrong with how I am converting `processedJson.get("company")` and `processedJson.get("dept_id")` to a string and int. What is going on here???

JSON:

```
{
"company":"CoolCarsInc",
"dept_id":16
}
```

Code:

```
// ITEM 7.2 - /department PUT
@Path("putdepartment")
@PUT
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
public Response putDepartment(
  String incomingJson
  ){
  
  //body comes in as a String, Circle is parsing it
  //or you would use String circleIn and parse it yourself
  //do some validation and update in db in either case
  
  DataLayer dl = null;
  Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
  String res = "";
  JsonElement receivedJson = new JsonParser().parse(incomingJson);
  JsonObject processedJson = receivedJson.getAsJsonObject();

  String company = processedJson.get("company").toString();
  String dept_name = processedJson.get("dept_name").toString();
  String dept_no = processedJson.get("dept_no").toString();
  String location = processedJson.("location").toString();
  int dept_id = processedJson.get("dept_id").getAsInt;
  
  try {
     dl = new DataLayer(processedJson.get("company"));
     
     Department oldDept = dl.getDepartment(company, dept_id);
     oldDept.setCompany(company);
     oldDept.setDeptName(dept_name);
     oldDept.setDeptNo(dept_no);
     oldDept.setLocation(location);
     oldDept.setId(dept_id);
     dl.updateDepartment(oldDept);

     Department updatedDep = dl.getDepartment(company, dept_id);
     res += gson.toJson(updatedDep);
     
   } catch (Exception e) {
     return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
  } finally {
     dl.close();
  }
  
  return Response.ok("updated department:\n" + res).build();

}
```

Comment: Can you clarify your questiona bit? If you do `dl.getDepartment(1, 1);` it works. But if you do `dl.getDepartment(company, dept_id);` where `company=1` and `dept_id=1` it fails? This has nothing to do with JSON nor Gson, does it? Please give the exact code what works and what does not.

Comment: @pirho sorry about that, thank you! I modified the question to show the exact code and spell out the problem better. You are correct except for `company` is a string instead of an int. Aside from that, I hope the question is clearer. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about gson. But you can also use org.json library of java.

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
```

Then wrap string into JSONObject.

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(incomingJson);
```

Then you can access the keys as :

```
json.getString("company");
json.getInt("dept_id");
```

For using this library include dependency in pom.xml as:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20190722</version>
        </dependency>
```